# ubuntu install python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

How can I easily install python 3.5 on ubuntu?
In this article https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/install-python-3-5-on-vivid-using-apt-get
write what im must run next comand

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.5
```

But im run

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
```

and its output next error

```
unable to execute /usr/bin/add-apt-repository: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4):

It comes by default when you run *the current release*:

```
edd@max:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.11+
edd@max:~$ python3.5 --version
Python 3.5.1+
edd@max:~$
```

So available but not yet the default python engine. That is using

```
edd@max:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
edd@max:~$
```

Comment: Good to know.  Please feel free to accept or upvote the answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Is software-properties-common installed? You can check by running *apt-cache search software-properties-common* On my 14.04 it shows:

```
$ apt-cache policy software-properties-common 
software-properties-common:
  Installed: 0.92.37.7
  Candidate: 0.92.37.7
  Version table:
 *** 0.92.37.7 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.92.36 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

If it isn't installed then try installing it using apt. I'm not sure why it wouldn't be installed though as it seems to be fairly core.

Also make sure that the directory /etc/apt/sources.list.d exists on your system.